# Put two array in googlechart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have two arrays:

> Sales [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
>   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

and

> Dates [01/03/2017, 02/03/2017, 03/03/2017, 04/03/2017, 05/03/2017,
>   06/03/2017, 07/03/2017, 08/03/2017, 09/03/2017, 10/03/2017,
>   11/03/2017, 12/03/2017, 13/03/2017, 14/03/2017, 15/03/2017,
>   16/03/2017, 17/03/2017, 18/03/2017, 19/03/2017, 20/03/2017,
>   21/03/2017, 22/03/2017, 23/03/2017, 24/03/2017, 25/03/2017,
>   26/03/2017, 27/03/2017, 28/03/2017, 29/03/2017, 30/03/2017,
>   31/03/2017]

I do not know if it's the right way, but I'm playing in a variable:

```
var dates= [
            <c:forEach var="a" items="${getDates}" varStatus="s">
            ['${a}'],
            </c:forEach>
            ];
```

and:

```
var sales= [
   <c:forEach var="b" items="${getSales}" varStatus="s">
     [${b}],
   </c:forEach>
];
```

I wanted to put this code and I can not:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Dates', 'Sales'],
          for (var i = 0; i <= dates.length; i++) {
            [dates[i], sales[i]],
}
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
```

Was that the logic? I have no idea how to fix it. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cannot place a `for` statement within a method call to `arrayToDataTable`

instead, create the `DataTable` first, then add the rows,

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var sales = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
  var dates = ['01/03/2017', '02/03/2017', '03/03/2017', '04/03/2017', '05/03/2017', '06/03/2017', '07/03/2017', '08/03/2017', '09/03/2017', '10/03/2017', '11/03/2017', '12/03/2017', '13/03/2017', '14/03/2017', '15/03/2017', '16/03/2017', '17/03/2017', '18/03/2017', '19/03/2017', '20/03/2017', '21/03/2017', '22/03/2017', '23/03/2017', '24/03/2017', '25/03/2017', '26/03/2017', '27/03/2017', '28/03/2017', '29/03/2017', '30/03/2017', '31/03/2017'];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'y');

  for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    data.addRow([dates[i], sales[i]]);
  }

  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 60
    },
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="curve_chart"></div>
```

---

**note**: the `Dates` array as posted in the question looks a little suspect

it should look more like the one in the above snippet

and if you want an actual `'date'` and not a `'string'`,

you'll need to build something like this...

```
var dates = [new Date('01/03/2017'), new Date('02/03/2017'), new Date('03/03/2017'), ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as I wanted it to. God bless you.